# Filter repetitive data with missing observations

Tags: r, dataframe, filtering

I have a data frame with roughly 20000 observations. The data consists of recordings from journeys along a single bus route, between stop 5 and 20. That is, ideally it would be a column = `stop` which would be repeating itself as in `5, 6, 7, ..., 19, 20, 5, 6, ...` etc. Unfortunately, there is missing data, so that is not always the case.

When there is missing data, I would like to remove the 3 following recordings from the same route. For instance, let's say I have a sequence as `5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20`, where the recording for stops `9` and `18` are missing. I then want to remove the rows of recording `10, 11, 12` and `19, 20`.

Is there a neat way to do this in R?

Currently, I am using `tidyr` to pivot the data, and remove incomplete observations that way, but that removes complete journeys instead of only the subsequent 3. Below is a mock data frame, my current implementation, and a data frame showing the desired output.

```
# Data
df <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1, 16), rep(2, 14)), 
                 stop=c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
                         5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20), 
                 time = rnorm(30))
# Extract the ids
ids <- df$id
# Create a journey based data frame with stops as columns and time as values
subset_df <- df %>% tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from='stop', values_from = 'time')

# Remove incomplete & ID column
rm_df <- subset_df[complete.cases(subset_df), ]

# Get the remaining ids
remaining_ids <- rm_df$id

# Subset the data frame with the complete cases
complete_cases_df <- df[is.element(df$id, remaining_ids),]
```

Output I would like to get:

```
df2 <- data.frame(id = c(rep(1, 16), rep(2, 9)), 
                 stop=c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
                        5, 6, 7, 8, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17), 
                 time = rnorm(25))
```

It would be nice with flexibility in deciding how many subsequent stops are removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be:

1. We bring in the correct order with `arrange(id, stop)`
2. The we create three columns gap, gap1, gap2, always lagged one row
3. This means 3 rows after the lacking number we now have TRUE
4. By filtering them out we get our result.

```
library(dplyr)


df %>%
  arrange(id, stop) %>%
  mutate(gap = stop - lag(stop, default = first(stop)) > 1, .by = id) %>%
  mutate(gap1 = lag(gap, default = gap[1]),
         gap2 = lag(gap1, default = gap1[1])) %>% 
  filter(!if_any(starts_with("gap"), ~. == TRUE)) %>% 
  select(-starts_with("gap")) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

```
 id stop        time
1   1    5 -0.22336881
2   1    6  0.36364387
3   1    7 -1.83544641
4   1    8  0.01814961
5   1    9 -1.30122669
6   1   10  0.84105979
7   1   11  1.65267900
8   1   12 -0.60058024
9   1   13 -0.08852824
10  1   14 -0.06700669
11  1   15 -0.83830797
12  1   16 -1.76628608
13  1   17 -1.04904130
14  1   18 -1.35796795
15  1   19 -0.12457266
16  1   20 -0.66617671
17  2    5 -0.44691032
18  2    6 -0.80684910
19  2    7 -0.58688365
20  2    8  0.69196557
21  2   13 -0.58865687
22  2   14  1.14572281
23  2   15  1.32314604
24  2   16 -1.17715578
25  2   17 -0.86947491
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Would it be possible to add a few comments with the code to help understand what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

```
subset(df, !ave(stop, id, FUN = \(x)x %in% 
           unlist(lapply(x[diff(c(4,x))>1], \(y)seq(y,by=1, length=3)))))

   id stop       time
1   1    5  0.3374932
2   1    6  0.2759855
3   1    7 -1.8097232
4   1    8 -0.3148637
5   1    9  0.1555224
6   1   10 -0.7753229
7   1   11 -2.3723279
8   1   12 -0.7845203
9   1   13  0.1387263
10  1   14  1.1845789
11  1   15  1.2969936
12  1   16  1.1421506
13  1   17 -2.5839955
14  1   18 -0.8345220
15  1   19  0.6228960
16  1   20 -1.4952315
17  2    5 -2.5591447
18  2    6  1.2018367
19  2    7  1.9759780
20  2    8 -0.4729620
24  2   13 -0.4501262
25  2   14  1.8839690
26  2   15  0.3628503
27  2   16 -2.0620141
28  2   17 -0.1574073
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Would you mind explaining what the FUN function does? I have a little hard following what's going on there =)